# Mixed-effect model design with a sampling variable

Tags: r, experiment-design, mixed-model

I am trying to specify a formula for a linear mixed effect model (with `lme4`) for my experimental design, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

The design: basically I'm measuring a response parameter on plants. I have 4 levels of treatment, and 2 irrigation levels.  The plants are grouped in 16 plots, within each plot I sample 4 sub-plots. In each sub-plot I take between 15 and 30 observations (depending on the number of plants found). That is, there are a total of 1500 rows.

[image]

Initially the subplot level was just here for sampling purposes, but I thought I'd like to take it into account in the model (as a 64-level variable) because I saw there was a lot of variability from one sub-plot to another, even inside the same plot (greater than the variability between whole plots).

My first idea was to write:

```
library(lme4)
fit <- lmer(y ~ treatment*irrigation + (1|subplot/plot), data=mydata)
```

or

```
fit <- lmer(y ~ treatment*irrigation + (1|subplot) + (1|plot), data=mydata)
```

Is that correct? I'm not sure if I must keep both plot/subplot levels in my formula. 
No fixed effect is significant but the random effects are very significant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your model should be written as

```
fit <- lmer(y ~ treatment*irrigation + (1|plot/subplot), data=mydata)
```

as subplots are nested within site. although `(1|plot)` + `(1|subplot)` would work *if* the subplots are uniquely labeled (i.e. 1A,1B,1C,...,2A,2B,2C rather than A,B,C...,A,B,C).  My book chapter from [Fox et al. *Ecological Statistics*](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780199672554.do) describes an example of nesting:

> On the other hand, in the tick example each chick occurs in only one brood,
>   and each brood occurs in only one site: the model specification is `(1 | SITE/BROOD/INDEX)`, read as “chick (INDEX) nested within brood nested within site,” or equivalently `(1 | SITE) + (1 | SITE:BROOD) + (1 | SITE:BROOD:INDEX)`. If the broods and chicks are uniquely labeled, so that the software can detect the nesting, `(1 | SITE) + (1 | BROOD) + (1 | INDEX)` will also work (do not use `(1 | SITE) + (1 | SITE/BROOD) + (1 | SITE/BROOD/INDEX)`; it will lead to redundant terms in the model).

Other thoughts:

- more information on nesting and model specifications at http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq
- are your irrigation treatments really organized as shown in the schematic above, i.e. non-interspersed? Or is that just for convenience of graphical presentation?  If the former, then you have a potentially problematic experimental design ...
- Since subplots are nested within sites, it would be just fine inferentially (following [Murtaugh 2007 *Ecology* "Simplicity and complexity in ecological data analysis"](http://www.esajournals.org/doi/abs/10.1890/0012-9658%282007%2988%5B56%3ASACIED%5D2.0.CO%3B2)) to take the plot means and analyze the data at the plot level.
- For what it's worth, I think you could go even farther and aggregate to the plot level; then you could skip mixed models entirely and just do `lm(y~treatment*irrigation, data=my_aggregated_data)`

Comment: thanks for your help (i have 12h to wait to unlock the +50 :(  indeed i was in big doubt concerning the naming of my subplots (4 or 64 unique labels). The figure is correct: irrigation is not "randomized", that's unfortunate i agree (they told me: "too expansive to do it differently"!). Thanks for the links. One more question: i get a residuals plot not looking good: cone-shaped (like this: "<"), error seems proportional to the Y values. is there a way to correct this in this type of model?

Comment: The most obvious solution (and one that often fixes other problems) is to transform the response, most often log-transforming.